# passing function variables to another file python

Tags: python, variables

I need to pass data_connection into my main.py engine because that variable is where the data from mysql string is being stored. In main.py it says parameter data_connection unfilled but I can only enter 'data_connection=' I'm confused what I'm supposed to do...

load_file.py

```
def get_connection():
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            "SELECT ID, Type, Server, Port, User, Password, isActive, FileExtension, FileContains, FileLocation, "
        "ScheduleMinutes, IntervalTime from DataConnection WHERE isActive=True")
    
        data_connection = cursor.fetchall()

def download_files(data_connection):

        for data_connection_detail in data_connection:
            # type email will be IMAP, POP3, or FTP
            connection_type = data_connection_detail[1]

            # create data_source object
            if connection_type == 'IMAP':
                ez_email.read_email_imap(data_connection_detail)

            elif connection_type == 'POP3':
                ez_email.read_email_pop3(data_connection_detail)

            elif connection_type == 'FTP':
                ez_ftp.easy_ftp(data_connection_detail)
```

main.py

```
from load_file import get_connection
from load_file import download_files

def run_engine():
    while True:
        get_connection()
        download_files()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_engine()
```

Comment: This example is missing parts. You have a file.py with a get_connection, but then you import a load_file module with a download_files function. If these are the same, please fix. Notice that we will want to run this code ourselves.

Comment: oops i didn't see that, those are the same files i edited it

Comment: Is there a `download_files` function in the module? Likely you want to return the object - replace `data_connection = cursor.fetchall()` with `return cursor.fetchall()` and then assign that to a variable in the function that calls it.

Comment: download_files is the function that is using 'data_connection' passed from the 'get_connection' function. I fixed and added the download_files function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data_connection` is a local variable in load_file.py that is destroyed when the function exits. You also have a like-named parameter in download_files. These are two different, unique variables created on each call to the function. They happen to have the same name, but in different namespaces so do not refer to the same thing.

The solution in this case is to return the object from the first function and use it as a parameter in the second.

load_file.py

```
def get_connection():
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            "SELECT ID, Type, Server, Port, User, Password, isActive, FileExtension, FileContains, FileLocation, "
        "ScheduleMinutes, IntervalTime from DataConnection WHERE isActive=True")
    
        return cursor.fetchall()

def download_files(data_connection):

        for data_connection_detail in data_connection:
            # type email will be IMAP, POP3, or FTP
            connection_type = data_connection_detail[1]

            # create data_source object
            if connection_type == 'IMAP':
                ez_email.read_email_imap(data_connection_detail)

            elif connection_type == 'POP3':
                ez_email.read_email_pop3(data_connection_detail)

            elif connection_type == 'FTP':
                ez_ftp.easy_ftp(data_connection_detail)
```

main.py

```
from load_file import get_connection
from load_file import download_files

def run_engine():
    while True:
        data = get_connection()
        download_files(data)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_engine()
```

Notice that I didn't use the variable `data_connection` in the first function at all, just returned its data. And when calling `download_files` I used a different name for the variable. This highlights the difference between a named variable in one context and the object it references in another context.

Comment: ok yes I see what you mean, i had been setting get_connection equal to data_connection from the first function. Thank you for your help this made things a lot more clear for me!